# how to check that mapreduce is running parallelly?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I submitted a mapreduce job and checked the log.
In the log l see that there are many mappers, each mapper processes one split, and the processing details of each mapper is logged in the log file sequentially in time.

However, I would like to check if my job is running parallelly and I want to see how many mappers are running concurrently.
I don't know where to find these informations.
Please help me, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following Jobtracker Web UI and drill down to executing MapReduce job

```
http://<Jobtracker-HostName>:50030/
```

Comment: I'm using the yarn framework, so I have to go to Resource­Manager's web UI (port 8088) to see the MapReduce details, am I right?